# Is it possible to add objects or data members to category in objective C?

Tags: iphone

we know that using category we can add functions to existing class. But i have a doubt that, Is it possible to add objects or data members to category in objective C ??

Comment: I have described one of the working approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887004/category-like-extension-for-instance-variables/4899521#4899521), which emulates such behavior, and doesn't require additional run-time routines implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you cannot add instance variables / members / properties via a category. You can only work with what the class you're expanding already offers, but of course your new methods may receive arguments upon being called.

Comment: You can use Objective-C associated objects. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Objective-C associated references. You can read the Apple documentation about them here: [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html)

Basically this lets you attach objects to any instance using the [objc_setAssociatedObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) function as follows:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

/* The key for the associated object must be void* so you can use a static variable to get a
   unique pointer. Alternatively you can use _cmd since selectors are constant and unique. */
static char key;
objc_setAssociatedObject(theInstanceToAddYourObjectTo,
                         &key,
                         @"The object you want to add",
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

To get the associated object again:

```
id value = objc_getAssociatedObject(theInstanceToAddYourObjectTo, &key);
```

And to clear the associated object, pass nil as the value:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(theInstanceToAddYourObjectTo,
                         &key,
                         nil,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
```

So using these functions you can add your own instance variables for use in category methods etc.

Comment: But this is limited to objects that you manually add, right? After all, the big advantage of categories is that you don't need to worry about which object will be able to use the added functionality...

Comment: Well presumably you want to add a property to an existing class using a category. To do that you simply define the setter/getter to use objc_setAssociatedObject etc. instead of @synthesizing the property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with associated objects is not possible to access it from method

```
  - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
```