# Category-like extension for instance variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to somehow **emulate** category behavior for a class regarding to it's instance variables, not methods ?

I have a `ClassA`, and I want to keep its name after extending it with new methods AND ivars from other cllass (`ClassB`).
Of course, I can inherit `ClassA`, but resulting class will have different name.

For methods addition, it's not a problem - category would be a good solution.

**UPDATE:** `ClassA` used as **file owner** for a XIB, and these fields to be extended are `IBOutlet`s. So I need them at build phase.

Comment: What's wrong with it having a new name? If you're trying to hack around class inheritance, there's probably a better way of doing what you're trying to do!

Comment: @deanWombourne: please, see updated question. Sometimes, there are situations when we need unusual approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've investigated this question playing around [*associative references*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html) (thanks to [Ole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887004/category-like-extension-for-instance-variables/4887205#4887205)), with methods static variables, methods swizzling, and finally come to this simple solution (no runtime stuff). I simply use "categorized" class only to return a pointer to a derived class, which of course can contain additional ivars. Doing so I achieve one unexpected benefit: I can call `super`'s class methods, which is impossible when extending through *categories*.

Example of a class extension (**tested**):

***ClassA+ClassB.h***

```
@protocol _ClassB_Protocol
  @optional // to avoid warnings
- (IBAction) onClick:(id)sender;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
@end

@interface ClassA (_ClassA_Category) <_ClassB_Protocol>
@end

@interface ClassB: ClassA <_ClassB_Protocol> {
    UIButton *aButton; // _ivar_ to add
}
@end
```

***ClassA+ClassB.m***

```
@implementation ClassA (_ClassA_Category)
// this will be called first on [ClassA alloc] or [ClassA allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone]
+(id) alloc {
    if ([self isEqual: [ClassA class]]) {
        return [ClassB alloc];
    } else {
        return [super alloc];
    }
}
@end


@implementation ClassB: ClassA

@synthesize aButton;

-(void) dealloc {
    [aButton release];

    [super dealloc]; // this is impossible for an ordinary category
}

- (void) onClick:(id)sender {
    // some code here
}

@end
```

Now we have in the same time:

- `ClassB` "extends" `ClassA` (category way);
- `ClassB` inherits `ClassA` (`ClassB` can call `ClassA` methods);
- `ClassB` can be accessed through `ClassA` name (category way)

Answer (score 6):

Since the iPhone uses the modern Objective-C runtime, you can use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to add data to instances without having to declare instance variables. See the documentation for [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) etc.

If you wrap the calls to the runtime in standard accessor methods, it will be very easy to use.

Comment: +1 for runtime level solution. However, I use `ClassA` as **file Owner** for a XIB, and these fields are `IBOutlets`. So, I need them at build phase. Sorry for not specified this detail.

Comment: What happens if you declare `@property (retain) IBOutlet id myVar;` in a category? Does it show up in IB?

Comment: Yes. Great suggestion! Going to try a simple case using associative references.

Comment: if you're curious, you can consider my answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

I put Martin's example into a trivial app replacing ClassA with NSData, ClassB with XXData, and onClick with getIvar, and invoked it (Mac OS X 10.6.6, Xcode 4 Final) with:

```
NSData * data = [NSData data];
NSLog(@"%@", [data getIvar]);
```

It fails with "-[NSConcreteData getIvar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" ..

It fails because "alloc" in the NSData category (which returns the pointer to the derived class) is not called by the above code.  If, instead, "alloc" is called explicitly, as in:

```
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [data getIvar]);
```

then all is well.

Comment: yes, there is an exception for this method. You should be aware when apply this technique to Class Cluster's. From this category are some built-in Cocoa's classes as: NSData, NSArray, etc.