# What's the right way to add methods and properties to a CoreData entity? Subclass them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to add additional properties and methods to entity classes that I'd like to decouple from the automatically generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

The class definition files that are automatically generated by Core Data are very helpful, and I like being able to change the data scheme and regenerate them quickly, without fear of wiping out my extensions, so subclassing feels like the right overall approach.

But when I do this (for example, subclass of `Person` called `MyPerson`) — that seems to function, but leads to confusion when using tools like MagicalRecord that are expecting the entity name to match the class name. (i.e. `[Person findAll]` works but `[MyPerson findAll]` fails because it finds no entity called `MyPerson`.)

Feeling like I'm banging my head against the wall too much; what is the right design pattern to pursue here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: try [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a *class category* where you define additional methods:

```
@interface Person (MyMethods)
- (NSString *)myMethod;
@end
```

This works nicely because Xcode will not overwrite the category files when
recreating the managed object subclass.

The only disadvantage is that you can
not add *instance variables* in a class category, and therefore no properties
which are backed up by instance variables.

There is one workaround: One can define a property in a class category and use 
"associated objects" to store their values (using Objective-C runtime methods
`objc_setAssociatedObject()`, `objc_getAssociatedObject()`, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601133/1187415 for an example.)

An **alternative** (as just mentioned in a comment) is to use "mogenerator".
mogenerator generates two  classes for each entity. One "machine" class (`_Person`)
that is always overwritten when you change the model,
and one "human" subclass (`Person`) where you can add 
methods, properties and instance variables as you like.

Comment: Thanks, I had used categories for this previously, but for what I want to add I really want to have instance variables (and properties). Thanks for the tip on mogenerator; will check it out. Would welcome any other alternatives as well.